# WriteLineAsync or ReadAsync unable to read string for TCP Communicator C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am creating a TCP Server/Client to communicate with each other using multithread and I'm having trouble getting the Server to correctly read strings that my Client is sending. For example, I send the string "testing" from the Client to the Server. On the server console, it instead reads "Received System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream". I've been stuck on it for a couple hours and I am at a loss at how to approach this situation. Any help with be greatly appreciated.

TLDR: Server and client can communicate with each other but server can't correctly read string sent from client.

Server Code:

```
async Task EchoAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            var buf = new byte[4096];
            var stream = client.GetStream();
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, ct);
                WriteToConsole("Received " + stream.ToString(), 0);
                if (amountRead == 0)
                {
                    break; // End of stream
                }
                await stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, amountRead, ct);
            }
        }
```

Client Code:

```
private async void ClientToServerMsg_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(NetworkStream))
            {
                //writer.AutoFlush = true;
                WriteToConsole("Writing to server...", 1);
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(ClientToServerMsg.Text);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
WriteToConsole("Received " + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf), 0);
```

Instead

```
     WriteToConsole("Received " + stream.ToString(), 0);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help!